# Is QFS supported on centos 6.4?

Tags: centos6, qfs

There is not any binary available of QFS for centos 6.4 as on link
https://github.com/quantcast/qfs/wiki/Binary-Distributions

I tried with QFS 1.0.2 and that did not work on Centos 6.4.

Could any one tell me- Is QFS supported on centos 6.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own packages:
https://github.com/quantcast/qfs/tree/master/contrib/package

You may want to ask a question on the QFS discussion group or search its archive: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/qfs-devel

Comment: Please add some snippets from your links, should they ever go down.